# Transform Scale on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Using this website as an example (https://hostmarked.dk/), I can see the second image down is inside an element, with 3 scalable elements also inside.

As you scroll the page, the 3 white elements reduce in size until the whole image is visible, then the effect stops.

I'm unsure how to link this scaling action to the scroll in jquery.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).scroll((e) => {
  // How much the user has scrolled
  let percentScrolled = window.scrollY / window.innerHeight;

  let minWidth = 100;
  let maxWidth = 200;
  // How wide the image should be
  let width = percentScrolled * (maxWidth - minWidth) + minWidth;

  let minHeight = 100;
  let maxHeight = 200;
  // How tall the image should be
  let height = percentScrolled * (maxHeight - minHeight) + minHeight;

  // The starting position
  let originalPosition = [100, 100];

  // Update width and height
  $(".fake-image").css("width", width + "px");
  $(".fake-image").css("height", height + "px");

  // Move the image so the center stays the same
  $(".fake-image").css("left", originalPosition[0] - (width - minWidth) / 2 + "px");
  $(".fake-image").css("top", originalPosition[1] - (height - minHeight) / 2 + "px");
});
```

```css
body {
  /* This just makes sure the whole page is scrollable */
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100vh;
}

.fake-image {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fake-image"></div>
```

This resizes and repositions the image when the window is scrolled. For more information, see the comments in the code.